# Door control with Arduino and limit switches

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to make a door with two limit switches and three buttons: one for stop and the other two for open and close. I run into a problem with the code with the start buttons and the limit switches. I can't make the code because I'm a beginner. Please can somebody help me with some code or something like that?

I'll appreciate it if you help me, because it's for my school project:)

Comment: Try something simpler first yourself: one button, try to read it; than a switch and try to read it; from there you make requirements for what you need. And if you run into a more specific problem you can ask again here; you also need a motor to open/close the door I assume?

Comment: Please provide a code that you have done, which is not working.

Comment: How does "help me with some code..." help you learn anything? There are many tutorials and example sketches to try out and build an understanding about how the Arduino can be used. There are no free lunches in the real-world :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write code to

1. Control a motor. Likely a DC motor with two way control. This can be done with four MOSFETs and several diodes or much better, one H bridge IC. Your code will need to determine which one of two lines going to the dc motor is getting connected to the positive rail, and which one to the negative/ground, or both disconnected, using the three buttons you described.
2. You will need to write code that monitors the limit switches. I would suggest you use interrupts for these. One pin goes to ground, the other goes to the Arduino interrupt pin. You can use attachInterrupt() function to write functions that execute right away. Make sure you read up on which pins on your Arduino will support interrupts.
3. You will need to stop the motor movement either directly or by throwing a switch using the interrupt (or whatever detection method you use for the limit switch).

*one special consideration is that any variables that you use inside of interrupt functions should be marked as volatile, so `int myVar;` becomes `volatile int myVar;`
*also don't use Serial.print or millis() inside of your interrupt functions if can avoid it.

---

From here Google 'Arduino switch' and work on an implementation of limit switches separately. If you want to, Google 'Arduino Interrupts' and improve your implementation to use interrupts. Next, Google 'DC motor bidirectional control Arduino'. Work on it standalone. Once both work separately, combine into a single project.

Let me know as you go through these if you have specific questions, and I would be happy to help you learn how to build it using the components you have.